# wordpress update records from dynamic fields

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a system in which new text fields are added dynamically in which new values can be entered . i want to update those values into database but since the values are dyanmic how can i get them and store them with php form submit ?

Html example

```
            <tbody>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row"><label for="user_limit_for_role">s2member level1</label></th>
                    <td><input type="text" id="" name="s2member_level1" value="400"></td>
                </tr>


                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row"><label for="user_limit_for_role">s2member level2</label></th>
                    <td><input type="text" id="" name="s2member_level2" value="400"></td>
                </tr>


                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row"><label for="user_limit_for_role">administrator</label></th>
                    <td><input type="text" id="" name="administrator" value="500"></td>
                </tr>


            </tbody>
```

in above html the name of the fields such as s2members_level1 and its value already exist in database and it coming there , but if user changes the value i need those to be updated and since a new member level record can be added on the spot dynamically increasing the row how can i update these values ?

for a single value i can use

```
$status = $wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_arete_bp_limit_settings SET limit_allowed='500' WHERE membership_role = 's2member_level1'");
```

But how to get values from dynamic input fields and store them accordingly .

Comment: make name="s2member_level[]" this way you can have an array of all the input fields.

Comment: but i need the name to update the correct value of correct membership

Answer (score 2):

```
           <tbody>
            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row"><label for="user_limit_for_role">s2member level1</label></th>
                <td><input type="text" id="" name="s2member_level[]" value="400"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row"><label for="user_limit_for_role">s2member level2</label></th>
                <td><input type="text" id="" name="s2member_level[]" value="400"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row"><label for="user_limit_for_role">administrator</label></th>
                <td><input type="text" id="" name="administrator" value="500"></td>
            </tr>


        </tbody>
```

Now, 
in your php,
you can loop through each s2member_level with

```
$arr = $_GET['s2member_level'];
foreach($arr as $s2member_level'])
{
   ... //do your job
}
```

Comment: sorry but i need those field name too `administrator` , `s2member_level1` `s2member_level2` so that i can update accordingly giving condition such as  `WHERE membership_role = 's2member_level1'"` or `WHERE membership_role = 's2member_level2'"` or `WHERE membership_role = 's2member_level1'"` but these fields are also dynamic and can be more